# How to include related field in query

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an Entity Called Attachment.

```
Id/Name/ParentId
```

I have a second entity called AttachmentVersion.

```
Id/AttachmentId/Size/Date/other unwanted fields
```

It is related by an Id.

This is the query I want to write.

```
_context.Attachments.Where(a=> a.ParentId == 5) 
//Include AttachementVersion.Size only in result.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get only most recent *AttachmentVersion*, then you should query *AttachmentVersions*:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var result = db.AttachmentVersions
    .Where(m => m.AttachmentId == attachmentId)
    .Include(m => m.Attachment)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Date)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

### Update

If you want to get list of attachments according to some filter, you can achieve what you want by querying *AttachmentVersions* and grouping them.

```
var result = db.AttachmentVersions
    .Where(m => m.Attachment.ParentId == 5)
    .Include(m => m.Attachment)
    .GroupBy(m => m.AttachmentId)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        // There will be one Attachment because we 
        // grouped by AttachmentId
        Attachments = g.Select(m => m.Attachment).Take(1),
        // Get only size of latest version
        Sizes = g.OrderByDescending(m => m.Date)
                .Select(m => m.Size)
                .Take(1)
    })
    // Load into memory to be able to use Single()
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(m => new
    {
        Attachment = m.Attachemts.Single(),
        LastSize = m.Sizes.Single()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Ah, I should have thought of that. :)

Comment: But I need a list, not a single Attachment.  I have revised the question to clarify.

Comment: But I don't want to include the full AttachmentVersion, as it is quite large (megs).  I only want the size.

Comment: And I only need Attachments.where(a=> a.ParentId == 5)

Comment: @GregGum, then I am afraid the only workaround is selecting anonymous type. If it is not a problem, I can update my answer.

Comment: @GregGum, and you want to get all in one query. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Comment: I am getting a compile error on the Select "The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121062/discussion-between-adil-mammadov-and-greg-gum).